# Updating organization name in android contacts programmatically

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to update the organization name in a single contact but it is not worked for me, I am using following code

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
   .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
   .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY,company)
   .build());
```

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote doesn't mention **which** contact you want to update.

A `Contact` is built from one or more `RawContacts`, you need to pass the `ContentProviderOperation` the `RawContact._ID` that you want to update.

Each `RawContact` is built from one of more `Data` entries, if you have the specific `Data._ID` you want to update, that'll be even better.

Assuming you only have the `RawContact._ID`, and it's `rawContactId`, then this should update it:

```
String selection = Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { rawContactId, CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
opt.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withSelection(selection, selectionArgs)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY, company)
         .build());
```

This tells the DB to update the data row(s) that belong to `rawContactId`, and are of type `Organization`

Answer (score 0):

```
String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"; 
String[] orgWhereParams = new String[]{String.valueOf(id), 
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}; 
operationList
.add(ContentProviderOperation
        .newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(orgWhere, orgWhereParams)
        .withValue(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA,
                guCon.getCompany()).build());
```